# Convert NAD27 to WGS84 with programming function like PHP

Tags: convert, coordinate-system, software-recommendations, wgs84, php

I am looking for a programming function that can convert NAD27 coordinates to WGS84.

I know QGIS could do the conversion, but I need a function for my purposes.

Comment: Where is your data geographically located? How accurate do you need the transform?

Comment: United States and Canada is where I'm converting. I don't need to be perfect. I'm trying to fix NAD27 points on Google maps as they're all off by like 150 ft. I converted NAD27 to NAD83 and put on google maps and it was about the same as WGS84 (maybe 5-8 ft difference). This would be acceptable for my purposes.

Comment: You'll want to use some third party tools to do the transform. GDAL/OGR are fairly robust and open source that are made for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use PHP, you could use [Proj4PHP](https://github.com/proj4php/proj4php). This is a PHP-Class for geographic coordinates transformation using [proj4](http://proj4.org/) definitions. Proj4php is an OSGeo community project.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for online API solution, you can use [MyGeodata Cloud](https://mygeodata.cloud) API - you can send data in many GIS formats and set transformation to any known projection and conversion to many GIS formats. Data can be post as file or as an URL link - as well as the result. In case you have coordinates in CSV file somewhere online, you can call this request:

```
https://mygeodata.cloud/api/convert?outform=url&format=csv&incrs=EPSG:4267&outcrs=EPSG:4326&srcurl=https://mygeodata.cloud/examples/data/points.csv
```

For more options see [API documentation](http://mygeodata.cloud/api).

Comment: Do you have any affiliation with MyGeodata Cloud?

Comment: I have to process millions of records, so an API would likely be too slow.